# Pandas groupby with lambda and in the list

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemType': ['Red', 'White', 'Red', 'Blue', 'White', 'White', 'White', 'Green'], 
               'ItemPrice': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 
               'ItemID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D']})
```

I would like get records (rows) with ItemIDs that contain only "White" ItemType in a form of a DataFrame

I have attempted following solution:

```
types = ['Red','Blue','Green']

~df.groupby('ItemID')['ItemType'].any().apply(lambda u: u in(types))
```

But this gives me an incorrect result (D should be False) and in a form of a series.

```
A False
B False
C True
D True
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using **`apply`** here, as it is usually quite slow.  Instead, assign a `flag` column before you `groupby`, and then use `all` to assert that none of a groups values are in `types`:

```
df.assign(flag=~df.ItemType.isin(types)).groupby('ItemID').flag.all()
```

```
ItemID
A    False
B    False
C     True
D    False
Name: flag, dtype: bool
```

---

However, just to demonstrate the logic of the operation, and show what was incorrect about your approach, here is a working version using `apply`:

```
~df.groupby('ItemID').ItemType.apply(lambda x: any(i in types for i in x))
```

You need to use `any` *inside* the lambda, as opposed to on the Series before using `apply`.

---

To access rows where this condition is met, you may use `transform`:

```
df[df.assign(flag=~df.ItemType.isin(types)).groupby('ItemID').flag.transform('all')]
```

```
  ItemType  ItemPrice ItemID
4    White         14      C
5    White         15      C
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to get results in a form of a Dataframe with only rows where this check is True? Usually I have to change Series to a Dataframe and then do outer merge with original Dataframe on a column. And then select rows from that Dataframe where this check equals True. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to calculate an array of non-white `ItemID` values. Then filter your dataframe:

```
non_whites = df.loc[df['ItemType'].ne('White'), 'ItemID'].unique()

res = df[~df['ItemID'].isin(non_whites)]

print(res)

  ItemType  ItemPrice ItemID
4    White         14      C
5    White         15      C
```

You can also use `GroupBy`, but it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This works as well. I have never used dataframe.ne before. Interesting solution.